# spreading the days and the number of repetitions of each person for each specific day in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

i have this table in postgresql database

```
id      name     time
1       poi      2018-05-13 08:45:48.846887
2       poi      2018-05-13 08:11:04.671437
3       roik     2018-05-14 16:32:04.671437
4       ceil     2018-05-14 17:38:04.671437
5       verk     2018-05-14 19:46:04.671437
6       roik     2018-05-16 08:21:04.671437
7       poi      2018-05-16 11:00:04.671437
8       roik     2018-05-18 14:40:08.671437
9       roik     2018-05-18 17:21:09.671664
10      verk     2018-05-13 08:46:04.671437
11      sant     ...
12      sant      ...
13      dmk       ...
14      roik      ...
15      poi       ...
...     ....     ...
```

I want to have such a table:

```
name 2018-5-1 2018-5-2 2018-5-3 2018-5-4 2018-5-5 2018-5-6 2018-5-7 2018-5-8 2018-5-9 2018-5-10 2018-5-11 2018-5-12 2018-5-13 2018-5-14 ...
poi  0        3         3         7
roik 0        4         2         1
verk 0        2         0         9
sant 1        0         8         2
dmk  0        3         ...
...
```

These numbers represent the number of repetitions of each person for each particular day
how can i do this??thank you in advance

Comment: look into crosstab extension

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you want but very similar to. You just need to translate "date" colun values to a columns itself, but you can easily do it on client after you queried the dates you need.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7r4AG9MV9zeZEjoU77fCfk/2

```
SELECT Test.name, SUM(CASE WHEN date(Test.time) = dates.date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), dates.date FROM Test CROSS JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT(date(time)) as date FROM Test) as dates
GROUP BY Test.name, dates.date
```

Comment: thank you nutic,but I want to have these people in one day between 1 hour intervals
count the number of repeaties of each person in each 1 hours of the specified time with the specified day